# Why my laravel link want to use another controller?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem. I created a link, but this link wants to do another thing. I tried to change everything, but that doesn't work. Why my link want to use another controller? Here's code:

```
 <a href="{{ action('SharedDataController@store') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Share data with this user</a>
```

Controller for this is here:

```
    public function store($id)
    {
        dd($id);
    }
```

That another controller:

```
public function getFilter($sport)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $users = $this->model->getUsers($sport);

    return view('filter.' . $sport, compact('user', 'users'));
}
```

Error:

```
[2017-09-17 18:57:56] local.ERROR: View [filter.share] not found. {"userId":1,"email":"rbartek.r100@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): View [filter.share] not found. at /var/www/html/SCE/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137)
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/share', ['uses' => 'SharedDataController@store']);    

Route::get('/{sport}', ['uses' => 'FilterController@getFilter']);
```

Comment: Do you have a route defined for `SharedDataController@store` ?

Comment: yes, i edited my code @NorrisOduro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a `post` request through an `<a>` tag. So Laravel picks the second `get` route instead of the `post` route.

Change the `Route::post('/share', ['uses' => 'SharedDataController@store']);` to
`Route::get('/share', ['uses' => 'SharedDataController@store']);`

Or wrap the logic in a form and use the `post` method instead of the `a` tag

Answer (score 0):

but what prevents to use this practice?

view.blade.php

```
<a href="/myLink" class="btn btn-primary">Share data with this user</a>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/myLink', 'SharedDataController@store');
```